# React/Javascript - Wait for variable to populate before running function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using a Google autocomplete geocoding input. I have it set up to handle the geocoding on change of the input(location selected), but also if the user hits the submit button after typing in a location without selecting from the autocomplete results. Once I get the user's selected location I am passing the lat/lng coordinates to the state of the parent component using a function `updateParentState()` What I would like to do is wait for the `lat` and `lng` variables to be populated before running that function. Currently the autocomplete portion of the function, the `if (place.geometry)` part of the condition, is working since `lat`/`lng` are populated instantly on change, but since Geocoding the raw input takes a bit, the `updateParentState()` function is running before `lat`/`lng` are populated. How can I adjust for this:

```
geocodeLoc = (place) => {
    var self = this;
    let lat = '';
    let lng = '';
    if (place.geometry) {
        // WORKS
        lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
    } else {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': place.name}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                // DOESN'T WORK
                lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            }
        });
    }
    self.props.updateParentState(
        lat, lng
    );
}
```

Comment: Just put it in the callback.

Comment: So I have to call the `updateParentState` function in two spots? Because if I put it in the callback, it will stop working for the first part of the condition unless I add it there as well.

Comment: Your geocoding code is asynchronous, so your code will move on to calling the `updateParentState` function while waiting for the other function to finish execution, causing your issue. As @tkausl said, just put your `updateParentState` function call in the callback as well

Comment: Yeah move it for the `else` branch into your callback, and for the `if` branch place it underneath there as well

Answer (score 1):

Call `self.props.updateParentState` in the callback of `geocoder.geocode` as well as at the end of the `if` block:

```
geocodeLoc = (place) => {
    var self = this;
    if (place.geometry) {
        const lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
        const lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
        self.props.updateParentState(lat, lng);
    } else {
        let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({'address': place.name}, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                const lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                const lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                self.props.updateParentState(lat, lng);
            }
        });
    }
}
```